# how can i retrieve a row(given as search) from postgresql and display the result in html page?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, postgresql

My problem is that I have to search a term (take as id). If I give a number to search, it should search the id in the table (take as result) of pgadmin3 (postgresql) and display the result table of particular row that I have searched in the HTML page.
My conditions are I can use only HTML5, CSS3, angular.js and not use jsp and servlets.
How can I retrieve data from postgres and display that in an HTML page?

Comment: As per my knowledge, you need a server side language to get the data from database whereas all html5 ,ccs3, angularjs are client side languages so I don't think you can do it only using these.

Comment: k tellme some methods so that i can go with that

Comment: there are many languages including the ones you mentioned (jsp, servlets) but you can choose as per your knowledge and requirements. Refer [this wiki link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_scripting#Languages) for the list

Answer (score 0):

With HTML (not a programming language), CSS (used for styling/visual appearance of a website) and AngularJS (a JavaScript Framework) you can't query a database.

Comment: k.just send me some links so that i go with that

Comment: It seems like you're lacking real basic understanding of how servers, databases, programming languages etc. work together. However:

Comment: You need to setup a local development environment first (just google XAMPP or LAMP stack, depending on if you're using Windows or Mac or Linux). Then you'll need to get familiar with a server side programming language like PHP or so. And then just follow tutorials how to establish a connection with the DB, query and return the data.

Comment: thank you..as iam a fresher im stuck in this.so please helpme out

Comment: I don't know your situation and what you need this for, but if you want to learn how to code I would start off with the basics. I can recommend https://www.codeschool.com/free for that, but there are many more sites and youtube channels which do a great job explaining stuff, just google for starting programming or something.

Comment: If you're absolutely lost, then maybe a book could be a good starting point as the content is structured and trustworthier than some forums maybe. But make sure you get books that are not too old (I would say not older than 2-3 years) as web technologies evolve fast.